# how to wait slideToggle finish before next button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
 $('.mybutton').click(function(){
 $('.someclasstohide').slideToggle(500)
 })
```

How do I make my button wait until the slide is finished?
I mean wait before the next click. If I add `insert.stop()`, it just stops spamming, not until `slideToggle` finishes.

Comment: so it is being animated on click what do you want to do

Comment: Do you mean you want the button disabled while the animation is taking place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmm, given that you want to make the button unclickable for the period of time the animation is running as opposed to stopping the animation (clearing the animation queue, which is usually done), I would take advantage of [JQuery's `slideToggle()` callback](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/#slideToggle-duration-complete).

Consider the sample code:

```
$('.mybutton').click(function(){
    // Disable the button
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);

    $('.someclasstohide').slideToggle(500, function(){
        // Reenable the button
        $('.mybutton').prop("disabled", false);
    });
})
```

Comment: The `$(this)` inside of the callback should be `$('.mybutton')`.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to detect if your element is being animated, and return. You can use the `animated` selector for this. If you want your button to be disabled, then @James' answer is the way to go.

```js
$('.mybutton').click(function () {
    
    var classToHide = $('.someclasstohide');
    
    if( classToHide.is(':animated') ) return;
    
    classToHide.slideToggle(500);
    
});
```

```css
#test {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="mybutton">
    Click me
</button>

<div id="test" class="someclasstohide"></div>
```